# Pass the value or name of a Nav tag in an OnClick event in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm having a silly little problem that I have not been able to solve and is, how to pass a value to my OnClick event? I need to pass it because it is the value of some values ​​of my menu and with them I am doing a process:

My onClick function:

```
  onClick() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ childVisible: !prevState.childVisible }));
  }
```

And my logic of my "Nav bar":

```
   <NavLink
                      onClick={() => this.onClick()}
                      value={"Spain"}
                      to="/other">
                      Spain
                    </NavLink>
       <NavLink
                      onClick={() => this.onClick()}
                      value={"EE.UU"}
                      to="/sidebar">
                      EE.UU
                    </NavLink>
```

After, I need recover the value(the name of Country (Spain or EE.UU)) pass of the OnClick function.

I understand that there are several posts of this but it does not work for me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried

```
   <NavLink
     onClick={() => this.onClick("Spain")}
     value={"Spain"}
     to="/sidebar">
     Spain
   </NavLink>
```

In your onClick function you will get the value

```
onClick(value) {
 console.log(value); //Spain
}
```

Comment: Yes, but then how do I recover it?

Answer (score 0):

you could use currying, note you may have to bind this or use arrow functions to auto bind the proper `this` context

```
  onClick(value) {
    // use value how ever you need
    this.setState(prevState => ({ childVisible: !prevState.childVisible }));
  }

  bindValueToClick(value) {
     return function() {this.onClick(value)};
  }

   <NavLink
     onClick={this.bindValueToClick("Spain")}
     value={"Spain"}
     to="/sidebar"
   >
     Spain
   </NavLink>
```